# Good materials available on internet to learn collection framework?

Tags: java, collections

Am a newbie in using java collection framework. What are the best possible resources online or books that I can make best use of?

Comment: A google search for java collections tutorial would have brought this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of these books:

[http://www.amazon.com/Certified-Programmer-Study-310-055-Certification/dp/0072253606](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072253606)

[http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208)

Comment: Your first link is a bit outdated. There's a more recent version: http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321002197&sr=1-1

Answer (score 0):

After the above referring to find out the internal logics of the collection framework in easy manner:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/

and search in the topics for the questions.

Regards,
Anand